# Get data from Google Analtics report from WebApi

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm building a Web Api and I need to get data from a Google Analytics report.
I need to get data from a Google Analytics view.
But I think I'm facing an issue with the credentials.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
        var filepath = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx";  
        var viewid = "XXXXXXXXXX";   
        GoogleCredential credentials;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string[] scopes = { AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly };
            var googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
            credentials = googleCredential.CreateScoped(scopes);
        }

        var reportingService = new AnalyticsReportingService(
            new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credentials
            });
        var dateRange = new DateRange
        {
            StartDate = "2018-06-01",
            EndDate = "2018-06-25"
        };
        var sessions = new Metric
        {
            Expression = "ga:pageviews",
            Alias = "Sessions"
        };
        var date = new Dimension { Name = "ga:date" };

        var reportRequest = new ReportRequest
        {
            DateRanges = new List<DateRange> { dateRange },
            Dimensions = new List<Dimension> { date },
            Metrics = new List<Metric> { sessions },
            ViewId = viewid
        };
        var getReportsRequest = new GetReportsRequest
        {
            ReportRequests = new List<ReportRequest> { reportRequest }
        };
        var batchRequest = reportingService.Reports.BatchGet(getReportsRequest);
        var response = batchRequest.Execute();
        foreach (var x in response.Reports.First().Data.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", x.Dimensions) + "   " + string.Join(", ", x.Metrics.First().Values));
        }
```

I'm getting the following issue:

```
  Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
  User does not have any Google Analytics account. [403]
  Errors [
  Message[User does not have any Google Analytics account.] Location[ - ] 
  Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
```

Thanks,
Andrés

Comment: You should read the help about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Right now your question doesn't seem to show any research effort or work on your part.

Comment: docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/libraries

Comment: I have uploaded the info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the credentials´ user has access to the Google Analytics account you are trying to access.
You must grant it access in the analytics page, just as you would for any other user.